# How can I insert a a row with first ID in non empty table?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with autoincrement id. This table is non empty.
I need to update my table for insert a new row with id 1.
How can I move my entire table one row down ?

My table :

```
Name : rem_taux

Column : rtx_id | rtx_code | rtx_taux | rtx_date
```

Thanks.

Comment: With an UPDATE statement

Comment: You shouldnt modifiy autonumeric columns, that mean you have to alter all the FK referencing that table too.

Answer (score 0):

three steps:

1. `update rem_taux  set rtx_id = rtx_id + 1;` to move rows down
2. alter sequence restart with next_val (or just select nextval)
3. insert you row with not default rtx_id value

like this:

```
 INSERT INTO rem_taux (rtx_id, rtx_code, rtx_taux, rtx_date)
 VALUES (1, <some>, <some>, <some>)
```

this is with assumption you dont have FK or other dependant structure

Comment: sorry to confuse :) and my keyboard is eating space and shit today - thank you for edit!